# Query field values from SQL Server Compact

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, constraintexception

```
(playerListTableAdapter.GetHeight(sortedPlayers[counter])
```

**"Sorted Players"** is an array of decimals, which match *primary keys*.

When I call the query **GetHeight**, I get the following error: *"ConstraintException was unhandled: Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints."*

The SQL statement for the query is:

```
SELECT        Height
FROM            PlayerList
WHERE        (Number = @PlayerID)
```

Note: In the database, **Number** is a *primary key*.

When we step through the execution, we can see that **sortedPlayers[counter]** does match a player in the database.

Any ideas on what causes this error?

Thanks!

-Dominique

Comment: What's the value of `sortedPlayers[counter]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fighting to get the query working, I discovered that I could access the value more directly by using the following syntax:

```
decimal? Player1Hgt = dsPlayerTeam.PlayerList.Rows.Find(sortedPlayers[counter]).Field<decimal?>("Height");
```

This allowed me to go pull the value from the database without using the tableAdapter query and is significantly simpler.

Incidentally, I did attempt to set the **EnforceConstraints** property of my tableAdapter to false, but it still threw the error.

Thank You for your help!

Comment: Really Nice! Congrats for solving the problem in a simpler manner.

Answer (score 2):

You add your primary key in your query

```
SELECT       YourPrimaryKey, Height
FROM            PlayerList
WHERE        (Number = @PlayerID)
```

Comment: If I do that, won't it try to return the primary key as well as the height? (Number from the WHERE statement is the primary key)

Comment: yes in order to localize your height target with your primary key, in order to modify good value

Comment: To be clear, I'm just trying to read the Height, i don't want to modify it.

Comment: but with your query if your don't set EnforceConstraints = false; you can't read

Answer (score 2):

To solve this you can set `EnforceConstraints` to `false` on the DataTable.

```
EplayerListTableAdapter.EnforceConstraints = false;
```

A more detailed answer is here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/c2c9158d-cddf-40cf-bf6c-794dc3ef9c7f/